# How do I move an icon (drag & drop) inside a JLabel to another JLabel instead of copying it?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, drag-and-drop, event-handling

I'm doing a school project for a chess game and I'm currently stuck at the DnD operation of the pieces.

In the code, I passed the TransferHandler.MOVE parameter in exportAsDrag() to make it a MOVE operation. However, the behavior of the TransferHandler is still COPY instead of MOVE, when dragging and dropping icon from JLabels.

I tried setting the icon of the source JLabel to null in exportDone() in TransferHandler anonymous class but the icon will disappear if the source and destination of the DnD operation is the same. If there is any more methods I should override/add or any other way to accomplish the same thing, please let me know about it.

```
MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
          ChessTiles c = (ChessTiles) e.getSource();
          TransferHandler handler = c.getTransferHandler();
          handler.exportAsDrag(c, e, TransferHandler.MOVE)
    }
};

private static TransferHandler handler = new TransferHandler("icon")
{
    @Override
    public int getSourceActions (JComponent c)
    {
        return MOVE;
    }
};

tileArray[x][y].addMouseListener(listener);
tileArray[x][y].setTransferHandler(handler);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried setting the icon of the source JLabel to null in exportDone() in TransferHandler anonymous class but the icon will disappear if the source and destination of the DnD operation is the same.

Yes, that needs to be done.

Also, by overriding the `importData(...)` method you can save the "target" component so you can check if the source/target are the same component:

```
TransferHandler iconHandler = new TransferHandler( "icon" )
{
    Component target;

    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c)
    {
        return MOVE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean importData(TransferSupport info)
    {
        target = info.getComponent();

        return super.importData( info );
    }

    @Override
    protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action)
    {
        if (action == MOVE
        &&  source != target)
        {
            ((JLabel)source).setIcon(null);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [documentation of `TransferHandler.exportDone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html#exportDone-javax.swing.JComponent-java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable-int-):

> Invoked after data has been exported. This method should remove the data that was transferred if the action was `MOVE`.

This should answer both question. First, you are indeed responsible to implement the move semantic and second, you should only do it when the `action` has the value `MOVE`. Besides the possibility of other transfer types, which doesn’t apply to your scenario, as you do not support them, it may get invoked with a zero action, to allow cleanup after an aborted transfer. This may even happen right from the `exportAsDrag` method when the preconditions were not met.

If you do not want to support dragging onto itself, you may disable the drop target temporarily, using the `exportDone` method for resetting the property.

E.g.

```
public class DragAndDropExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(DragAndDropExample::init);
    }

    private static void init() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch(ReflectiveOperationException|UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {}
        try {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(
                new URL("https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png"));
            img = img.getSubimage(0, 11844, 32, 32);
            ICON = new ImageIcon(img);
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ICON = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        Container c = frame.getContentPane();

        final int gridWidth = 4, gridHeight = 4;
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(gridHeight, gridWidth, 4, 4));
        for(int y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++) {
                create(x, y, c);
            }
        }

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static Icon ICON;

    static final MouseAdapter DRAG_INIT = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            var c = (JComponent) e.getSource();
            var handler = c.getTransferHandler();
            handler.exportAsDrag(c, e, TransferHandler.MOVE);
        }
    };
    static final TransferHandler ICON_TRANSFER = new TransferHandler( "icon" ) {
        @Override public void exportAsDrag(JComponent comp, InputEvent e, int action) {
            comp.getDropTarget().setActive(false);
            super.exportAsDrag(comp, e, action);
        }
        @Override public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
            return MOVE;
        }
        @Override protected void exportDone(
                                 JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {
            source.getDropTarget().setActive(true);
            if (action == MOVE) {
                ((JLabel)source).setIcon(null);
            }
        }
    };
    private static void create(int x, int y, Container c) {
        JLabel l = new JLabel("\u00a0");
        if(x == 0 && y == 0) l.setIcon(ICON);
        l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.lightGray, 1));
        l.setTransferHandler(ICON_TRANSFER);
        l.addMouseListener(DRAG_INIT);
        c.add(l);
    }
}
```

If you do not want to disable it, you may store the component, to check whether source and target are the same like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57932304/2711488), but you should set the remembered component to `null` in the `exportDone` method, to ensure that there are no memory leaks.

Comment: (1+) I knew there had to be a better way to prevent a component from dropping on itself. Using the `setActive(...)` method makes more sense to me then tracking the source/target components across methods.

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested that I override the exportDone(...) function of TransferHandler like so,

```
@Override
    protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action)
    {
        if (action == MOVE)
        {
            ((JLabel)source).setIcon(null);
        }

        //((JLabel)source).setIcon(null);
    }
```

Without the if the statement, if I set the icon to null, the icon will disappear, regardless of the bool returned by importData(...). With it, the icon stays if the returned value of importData(...) is false. So is it safe to assume that after importData(...) is called, then only exportDone(...) is called?

It works but now I'm curious about the sequence of TransferHandler's internal function calls, after handler.exportAsDrag(...) is invoked.

Comment: *It works but now* - I think I made that suggestion and then deleted it because it didn't work properly. I found that if I clicked and released the mouse without dragging to another component, the Icon was removed. I provided a new suggestion that works in my simple tests.

Comment: Since there are more than one illegal moves to check, isn't it better to have the exportDone(...) implementation remain like this and to check the move in the importData(...) function by using a legalMove flag to decide whether to return super.importData(...) or false (if the flag is false) inside the importData(...) function. Thanks a lot for clearing up my confusion, man.

Comment: *Since there are more than one illegal moves to check* - this is a more complex question since the TransferHandler now needs to know the logic of your application and the current state of your application. In this case I would suggest you override the canImport(...) method. As you drag the Icon from label to label, the dragging Icon will remain as a "circle with a line through it" until you hover over a label that can accept the transfer at which time it changes to the "move" icon.